# "Subscription class not found" with ActionCable and Rails 6 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, redis, actioncable

I use `ruby 3.0.2p107`, `Rails 6.1.6` and I've a Rails backend (API) and a React Typescript frontend.

**Backend code**

```
# app/channels/notification_channel.rb
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notification_channel_#{current_user.user_id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed; end
end
```

```
# app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_user
    end

    private 

    # search the current user
    def find_user
      current_user = Profile::Account.find_by(user_id: request.query_parameters[:user_id])
      current_user ? current_user : reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
  end
end
```

**Frontend code**

```
    const createSubscription = (consumer: ActionCable.Cable) => {
        consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: `notification_channel_${user.sub}` }, {
            connected: () => console.log(`connected to notifications.${user.sub}`),
            received: (notification) => handleReceivedNotification(notification),
        });
    };

    const handleReceivedNotification = (notification: any) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(notification));
    }

    useEffect((): void => {
        if (user) setComsumer(ActionCable.createConsumer(`ws://localhost:3100/cable?user_id=${user.sub}`));
    }, [user]);

    useEffect((): void => {
        if (consumer) createSubscription(consumer);
    }, [consumer]);
```

When I run the app (backend and frontend) I get the connection but can't find the subscription class.

```
Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vYXBpL1Byb2ZpbGU6OkFjY291bnQvMQ)
Subscription class not found: "notification_channel_facebook|10157537128720479"
```

Also if I try a broadcast from command line, it does not work out (returns 0).

```
$ ActionCable.server.broadcast "notification_channel_#{user.user_id}", { action: "new_notification" }
D, [2022-07-07T14:44:03.820530 #19220] DEBUG -- : [ActionCable] Broadcasting to notification_channel_facebook|10157537128720479: {:action=>"new_notification"}
=> 0
```

I checked also the Redis channels but I can't find the `notification_channel`.

```
Redis.new.pubsub("channels")
=> ["action_cable/Z2lkOi8vYXBpL1Byb2ZpbGU6OkFjY291bnQvMQ", "_action_cable_internal"]
```

Here my `config/cable.yml` config file

```
default: &default
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV['REDIS_URL'] %>
  channel_prefix: api_production
```

Here the imports of `config/application.rb`

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
# activate the action mailer system
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
```

I believe I've been through all the documentation I could find about the topic, but I'm starting loose on options. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've been finding an answer thanks to [this article](https://sulmanweb.com/action-cable-for-rails-api/)

As the action cable to be used by API and client is not on rails, go to `config/application.rb` and include:

```
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
config.action_cable.url = "/cable"
```

Also I realized that the user identified needs to be used only in the connection phase, while for the subscription I need to use the module name.

```
consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: `NotificationChannel` }, {
  received: (notification) => handleReceivedNotification(notification),
});
```

Now if I broadcast a message, it works smoothly

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "notification_channel_#{user.user_id}", { action: "new_notification" }
```